# JavaScript/AppsScript Google Sheets: Loop Copy and Paste Cell Value Below, While Condition is Met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop

#### Background:

I've been trying to do what seems like a fairly simple task with Apps Script and Google Sheets; but it seems my Javascript/AppsScript knowledge is lacking.

I have one column that has Event data. Wherein there are many random string values between a recurring ***roundstart*** and ***roundend***.

A `roundstart` will always be followed by a `roundend`. However, there are events that occur in between rounds, and thus outside of a given `roundstart`/`roundend`.

I have looked over MANY similar questions, and all seem to have some fundamental difference in the problem.

#### Summary:

- Iterate through every cell in the `Round` column
- Start repeating a cell value when the value to the left = `roundstart`
- Stop repeating the cell value when the value to the left = `roundend`

#### Current Structure:

```
[Event]     [Round]
  a       
  b
roundstart    1
  x
  y
  z
roundend
  a
  g
  k
roundstart    2
  h
  g
roundend
roundstart    3
  a
  z
roundend
```

#### Desired Output:

```
[Event]     [Round]
  a       
  b
roundstart    1
  x           1
  y           1
  z           1
roundend      1
  a           
  g
  k
roundstart    2
  h           2
  g           2
roundend      2
roundstart    3
  a           3
  z           3
roundend      3
  g
  b
```

#### Current Attempts (if you can call them that):

The logic behind this seems straightforward, but I encounter an error in just about every attempt I make. Suspect it is due to my poor understanding of JS syntax...

```
function Repeat_Rounds() {
  var events_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rounds_range = event_sheet.getRange("B2:B200").getValues();
//Feel like there is probably a better way to call out the Rounds column range, but this works for now

 rounds_range.forEach(function(cell) {

//if the cell is not null and the cell one column left != "roundend", then...
    if cell.value > 0 and cell.offset(0,-1).value != "roundend" { 

//...copy & paste the current value, one row down
      cell.value.copyTo(cell.offset(0,1))   

     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Repeat_Rounds() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  let rg = sh.getRange(2,1,getColumnHeight(1,sh,ss),2);
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  let v;
  vs.forEach(r =>{
    if(r[0]=='roundstart') {
      v = r[1];
    }
    if(r[0] && r[0] != 'roundend') {
      r[1] = v;
    }
    if( r[0] == 'roundend') {
      r[1] = v;
      v = '';
    }
  });
  rg.setValues(vs);//You might not want to do this if you have formulas within the range.  I did it because it was simple but I could have set them with setValue() into individual cells but it's much slower.
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

Sheet 2 Before:

| [Event] | [Round] |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b |  |
| roundstart | 1 |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| z | 1 |
| roundend | 1 |
| a |  |
| g |  |
| k |  |
| roundstart | 2 |
| h | 2 |
| g | 2 |
| roundend | 2 |
| roundstart | 3 |
| a | 3 |
| z | 3 |
| roundend | 3 |

Sheet 2 after:

| [Event] | [Round] |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b |  |
| roundstart | 1 |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| z | 1 |
| roundend | 1 |
| a |  |
| g |  |
| k |  |
| roundstart | 2 |
| h | 2 |
| g | 2 |
| roundend | 2 |
| roundstart | 3 |
| a | 3 |
| z | 3 |
| roundend | 3 |

Comment: Thank you @MetaMan! Works Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
function Repeat_Rounds() {

  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range  = sheet.getRange("B2:C30");
  var rounds = range.getValues();
  
  for (var i=0; i<rounds.length; i++) {

    var cell_right = rounds[i][1];
    var cell_left  = rounds[i][0];

    if (cell_left == "roundstart") { var round = cell_right; continue; }
    if (cell_left == "roundend")   { var round = ""; continue; }
    if (!cell_right) rounds[i][1] = round;

  }

  range.setValues(rounds);
}
```